# Tkinter Grid only has two columns

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to understand exactly how the grid method works in Tkinter. When I set the column for one of my widgets to 0, it gets put to the middle, when I add a sticky it gets put to the left. However, setting the column to 1 will put it to the right. I am confused as to why there are only two columns in my entire grid and if there is a way to configure how I want my window sliced up.

```
from tkinter import *
import vlc

window = Tk()

window.geometry("1024x640")

window.title("Python-VLC Video Player")

window.grid_columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
window.grid_rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)

window.wait_visibility()

screen_width = window.winfo_width()
screen_height = window.winfo_reqheight()

topFrame = Frame(master=window, width=screen_width, height=100)
topFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, pady=20, sticky='w')

searchBox = Entry(master=topFrame, relief=SUNKEN, width=50)

searchBut = Button(master=topFrame, width=10, text="Load")

searchBox.grid(column=0, row=0)
searchBut.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5)

videoFrame = Frame(master=window, width=600, height=480, bg="grey")
videoFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Column set to 1, sticky set to West
[image: Column set to 1]

Column set to 0, sticky set to North
[image]

Comment: Try using `sticky = 'nsew'` this will make it stick on all sides.

Comment: [This](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused as to why there are only two columns in my entire grid

There are only two columns because you have only put widgets in two columns. The only columns are those with widgets in them. Empty rows and columns have a size of zero.

> When I set the column for one of my widgets to 0, it gets put to the middle, when I add a sticky it gets put to the left.

Yes, this is working as designed. When you move the other frame to column 0, you only have a single column with two frames. By default widgets will be centered in the column. Without setting `sticky` the frames will be centered. When you set the `sticky` to "w"  you're asking it to be on the left side of the only column.

> if there is a way to configure how I want my window sliced up.

Yes, of course there's a way. You can have as many columns as you want, limited only by the resolution of your screen and the size of your window. You didn't specify what you want it to look like so we can't give any concrete advice.

The way the gridder works is well documented. The canonical documentation is for the tcl/tk library, but it's easily translated into python. See [The grid algorithm](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm#M33) for a description of exactly how `grid` works.